# validate firstname and lastname

Tags: javascript, php, validation, detect

First my English is not so good, so please understand what I am trying to say.

I previously asked this ***[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724590/disallow-mixed-language-characters-in-firstname-and-lastname)***, but I did not get an answer that I wanted. That's why I write this question.

---

I want users to be able to set their name in any language. But there are some rules:

#### Names can’t include:

- Symbols, numbers, unusual capitalization
- Characters or punctuation or icon that is not in any language, like this(⧇ ⧈ ⧉ ⧊ ⧋ ⧌⛋ ⛌ ⛍ ⛎ ⛏ ⛐ ⛑ ⛒ ⛓ ⛔)
- Characters from multiple languages

How can I validate names with these kind of rules?

Comment: What is considered as *unusual capitalization*?

Comment: ignore this and see next two rules

Answer (score 3):

It is a suggestion, you can give a try to Regual Expressions, named also Regex.

Check this out:
[8 Regular Expressions You Should Know](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/)

Hope it gives you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need some pretty specific preg_match rules. If you take some of the advice from the previous question you asked and mash that up with that language detection service you found, you should be able to detect the language, then compare the first and last name against a pre-defined list of unacceptable characters and, if you find them, reject the name. After that check, you should be able to check the first name language, the last name language, then compare those results and figure out if they are in the same language and, if not, reject.

Comment: but list of unacceptable characters is very long, in other words all character that is not in any language

Comment: I think the regex idea above it probably the best solution, but just to continue down the path I was going down, you would detect the language first (let's say it comes back as english), so then you would have an array of english characters that are unacceptable, so then you would have a preg_match or regex that compares your statement to that array.

Comment: I thing this regex ` '/^[\p{L}\p{M}]+$/u' `can be do something for me,but don't know this is secure or not